How to get not active object?
What I'm trying to do is select two objects, add Data Transfer modifier to active object in selection and then use not active as source.
So, active object is bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
How can I get not active one? The one was selected first.


You can exclude active object from bpy.context.selected_objects

Selected objects are queried with bpy.context.selected_objects.
The active object is queried with bpy.context.active_object.
Thus you can query all selected, non active objects with something like selected_and_not_active_objects = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o != bpy.context.active_object]
If you have only 2 selected objects and one active object you can do something like selected_and_not_active_object = next(o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o != bpy.context.active_object)
